# requesting Canvas Text and requestAnimationFrame assistance

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, requestanimationframe

I have been working on an issue for a few days now and have been unable to solve it.  Please note that I am relatively new to Javascript so not sure if what I have below is the best way to accomplish this but going through this over the last few days has definitely helped me learn some new things.

Also, please note I know I could achieve this very easily using CSS but I wanted to know if there was a Javascript/JQuery solution.

The Issue:
    I am attempting to simulate a fadeIn animation on a canvas for some text.

```
var introText =
{
    "Welcome To A New Day...": "75",
    "Full Service Web Design": "50",
    "by": "50",
    "J. David Hock": "50"
};
```

The numbers represent font size.

Here is the full code:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var canvas = $('#myCanvas')[0];
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var introText =
    {
        "Welcome To A New Day...": "75",
        "Full Service Web Design": "50",
        "by": "50",
        "J. David Hock": "50"
    };


    function fadeText(timeStamp, t, x, y)
    {
        var opacity = timeStamp / 1000;
        console.log('Timestamp: ' + timeStamp + ' Opacity: ' + opacity);
        console.log('t, x, y |' + t +' | ' + x + ' | '  + y)
        //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        //ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(178, 34, 34, ' + opacity + ')';
        //ctx.fillText(t, x, y);

        if (opacity < 1)                   
        {
            requestAnimationFrame(function (timestamp)
            {
                fadeText(timestamp, t, x, y)
            });
        }
    }

    function MessageObject(x, y, f, fs, t)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.f = f;
        this.fs = fs;
        this.t = t;
    }

    var msgArray = [];

    function CreateMessageArray(myArray, callback)
    {   
        var i = 0;
        var v = 75;

        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        var f = '';
        var fs = '';
        var t = '';


        for (t in myArray)
        {
            fs = myArray[t];                                                    //font size
            f = 'italic ' + fs + 'px Bradley Hand';                             //font type
            x = (canvas.width / 2)                                              //x pos of text
            msgArray.push(new MessageObject(x, y, f, fs, t))
            y = Number(fs);
            //alert('x, y, f, t | ' + x + ' | ' + y + ' | ' + f + ' | ' + t);
        }

        return callback(msgArray);
    }

    let ProcessMessageArray = function (myArray)
    {
        var xPrime = 0;
        var yPrime = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
        {
            var msgObject = myArray[i];

            var x = msgObject.x;
            var y = msgObject.y;
            var f = msgObject.f;
            var fs = msgObject.fs;
            var t = msgObject.t;

            ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
            ctx.font = f;
            var txtWidth = ctx.measureText(t).width

            xPrime = x - (txtWidth / 2);

            requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp)
            {
                fadeText(timestamp, t, x, y)
            });

            //ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(178, 34, 34, 1)';
            //ctx.fillText(t, xPrime, yPrime);

            if (i === 0)
            {
                yPrime = Number(yPrime) + (2 * Number(fs) - 35);
            }
            else
            {
                yPrime = Number(yPrime) + Number(fs);
            }
        }
    }

    CreateMessageArray(introText, ProcessMessageArray)

});
```

The way it is supposed to work is that the CreateMessageArray function creates an array of objects that contain the x-pos, y-pos, etc. for each of the lines of text in the introTextArray.

The ProcessMessageArray is then responsible for outputting each line of text in the introTextArray into it proper position on the screen.

In the ProcessMessageArray there is a call to a requestAnimationFrame function where I was hoping it would "fade in" each line of the text but what is actually occurring is that I am only getting the last line of text in the IntroTextArray.

I am sure it has to do with the fact that I am calling a requestAnimationFrame within a loop but I am not sure how to accomplish what I want to otherwise.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Animating with requestAnimationFrame

- RAF `requestAnimationFrame`

There are many ways that you can use RAF to animate.  You can have many RAF functions that will all present the content to the display at the same time if they are all called before the next refresh. But this does incur extra overhead (especially if the rendering load per item is small) and extra head pain. If you have a slow render (for whatever reason, browsers can hang for a 1/60th second without warning) it can mess up the presentation order and you will only get part of the frame rendered.

The easiest way to manage any type of animation is to have a single animation loop that is called via RAF. From that function you call your animations. This is safe from presentation order problems, and can easily switch state. (eg after text fade you may want something else fading in)

#### Fix

Your code was not able to be saved, and sorry, was DOA, so I rewrote the whole thing. I have added some notes in the comments as to why and what for but if you have questions please do ask in the comments.

The example displays the fading text as two sets (to illustrate changing display state, a state is an abstract and reference to related elements or render (eg intro, middle, end))

The function has one main loop that handles the rendering calls and the timing.

Text is displayed by a function that updates and then displays. it will return true when text has faded in so main loop can set up the next render state.

```js
// Removed jQuery and I dont see the need to use it
// The convention in JavaScript is NOT to capitalize the first character
// unless you function / object is created using new ObjectName

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  // canvas is named in HTML via its id
canvas.width = innerWidth; // window is the global scope you do not need 
canvas.height = innerHeight; //to prefix when accesing its properties

// helper
//const log = (...data) => console.log(data.join(","));

// use an array it is better suited to the data you are storing
const introText = [
  ["Testing one two.", 75],
  ["Testing..." , 50],
  ["One, one two.", 50],
  ["Is this thing on?", 50],
  ["",1], // to delay next state
  ["",1], // to delay next state
];
const introText1 = [
  ["Second stage, state 2", 20],
  ["The End" , 40],
  [":)", 30],
  ["",10],
  ["Thanks for watching..",12],
  ["",1],
  ["",1],
  ["Dont forget to vote for any answers you find helpfull..",10],
  ["",1],
  ["",10],
  ["This intro was brought to you by",12],
  ["",10],
  ["requestAnimationFrame",12],
  ["HTML5",12],
  ["canvas",12],
  ["JavaScript (AKA) ECMAScript6",12],
  ["",10],
  ["Staring...",14],
  ["Stackoverflow.com",18],
];
const TEXT_FADE_TIME = 1000; // in ms

// create the array of display arrays
const displayLists = [
   createDisplayList(8, introText), // converts simple text array to display list
   createDisplayList(8, introText1),
];
var curretDisplayListIdx = 0;

requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); // will start when all code has been parsed

var startTime;
function mainLoop(time){  // keep it simple use one animation frame per frame
  if(startTime === undefined) { startTime = time }
  const timeSinceStart = time - startTime;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
  if (textFadeIn(timeSinceStart, curretDisplayListIdx )) {
     if (curretDisplayListIdx < displayLists.length - 1) {
         curretDisplayListIdx += 1;
         startTime = time;
     }
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

// creates a display list from text array. top is the start y pos
function createDisplayList(top, array) {
  const result = [];
  var y = top;
  var fontSize;
  for (const item of array) {  
    const fontSize = item[1];
    result.push({
      font : 'italic ' + fontSize + 'px Bradley Hand',
      text : item[0],    
      x : canvas.width / 2,
      y , fontSize,
      startTime : null,
      fadeTime : TEXT_FADE_TIME,
      alpha : 0, // starting alpha
    });
     y += fontSize;
  }
  return result;
}
// displays a text display list from the displayLists array. 
// time is time since starting to display the list 
// displayListIdx is the index
// returns true when text has faded in
function textFadeIn(time, displayListIdx) {
  // complete will be true when all have faded in
  const complete = updateDisplayList(displayLists[displayListIdx], time);
  renderDisplayList(displayLists[displayListIdx]);

  return complete;

}

// separate logic from rendering
function updateDisplayList(array, time) {
  var fadeNext = true; // used to indicate that the next item should fade in
  // for each item
  for (const text of array) {
    if (fadeNext) { // has the previous items done its thing?
      if (text.startTime === null) { text.startTime = time }
    }
    if(text.startTime !== null){  // if start time is set then fade it in
        text.alpha = Math.min(1, (time - text.startTime) / text.fadeTime);
        if (text.alpha < 1) { fadeNext = false }  // if not complete flag fadeNext to stop next text fading in
    }
  }
  // if last item is fully faded in return true
  return array[array.length - 1].alpha === 1;

}

// seperate rendering from logic
function renderDisplayList(array) {
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  for (const text of array) {
    ctx.font = text.font;
    ctx.globalAlpha = text.alpha;
    ctx.fillText(text.text,text.x,text.y);
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hello Blindman67, thank you very much for this, I just saw your answer and will review but wanted you to know how much I appreciate you taking the time to write this out for me.  Awesome!!